# About glm quaternion rotation

Tags: opengl, quaternions, glm-math

I want to make some rotation by quaternion.

The glm library was done this very well.

The following was my codes:

```
vec3 v(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
float deg = 45.0f * 0.5f;
quat q(glm::cos(glm::radians(deg)), 0, glm::sin(glm::radians(deg)), 0);
vec3 newv = q*v;
printf("v %f %f %f \n", newv[0], newv[1], newv[2]);
```

My question is which in many articles the formula of the rotation by quaternion was

```
rotated_v = q*v*q_conj
```

It's weird. In glm the vector "v" just multiply by the quaternion "q" can do the rotation.

It confused me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing some research. 
I found the definition of the operation "*" in glm quaternion and what is going on in there.

This implementation is based on those sites.

[Quaternion vector rotation optimisation](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/205),

[A faster quaternion-vector multiplication](https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2013/05/24/a-faster-quaternion-vector-multiplication/),

Here's two version of the rotation by quaternion.

```
//rotate vector 
vec3 qrot(vec4 q, vec3 v) 
{ 
    return v + 2.0*cross(q.xyz, cross(q.xyz,v) + q.w*v);
}
```

---

```
//rotate vector (alternative) 
vec3 qrot_2(vec4 q, vec3 v)
{ 
    return v*(q.w*q.w - dot(q.xyz,q.xyz)) + 2.0*q.xyz*dot(q.xyz,v) +    
          2.0*q.w*cross(q.xyz,v);
}
```

If someone can proof that. 
I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The confusion stems from the GLM multiplication operator between quaternion and a vec3. It does **NOT** perform a quaternion multiplication as one would assume - it performs a vector rotation operation as you described it above. For this reason the `rotated_v = q*v*q_conj` will give incorrect results. See: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62937791)

Answer (score 1):

It works when the imaginary part of your quaternion is perpendicular with your vector.

It's your case vec3(0,sin(angle),0)  is perpendicular with vec3(0,0,1);

You will see that you need to multiply by the conjugate when it's not right.

q quaternion, v vector.

when you do q * v normally you will obtain a 4D vector, another quaternion. 
We just don't care about the first component and assume it's 0, a pure quaternion. when you do q * v * q' you are sure to obtain a pure quaternion which translate to a good 3D vector

You can test with non perpendicular vector/quaternion and you will see that your rotation is not right

https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-quaternions/

Comment: In fact, I ever try to do q * v * q' to obtain rotated vector. But it's incorrect.
something like,
    `quat q(cos(radians(deg)), 0, sin(radians(deg)), 0);
    quat q_conj = conjugate(q);
    vec4 newv= vec4(0, v);
    newv = q*newv*q_conj;`

And I got (0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,1.000000)

Comment: It looks like do nothing.

Comment: I have a peace of code working well   `quat tmp = mix(m_init,m_end,t);
vec3 res=  tmp * m_initTargetVector * conjugate(tmp));` you don't need the vec4 "newv"

Comment: Okay, if you take a look the definition of glm::rotate. You'll see it just do what I do. `return q * v;` where q is quat, v is vec3.